# How can ASP.NET MVC takes more than 10 Seconds to load (for the first time) a blank Controller?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, performance, iis, publish

I'm managing an `ASP.NET MVC` application which use (basically) `.NET MVC` and `Entity Framework`. I notice that every time I Publish the website, it takes very long time (around 10-15 seconds) every time I load (for the first time) each `Controller/Action`.

I thought it was some `Entity` problem, so I've created a blank `TestController/Index` and place a simple `View` code:

```
// Controller
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}

// View Index.cshtml
test page controller Page generated in @((DateTime.UtcNow - HttpContext.Current.Timestamp.ToUniversalTime()).TotalSeconds.ToString("F4")) seconds
```

Than I publish the website using `Visual Studio` (`FTP` mode).

Once published, I call from browser a separate/generic/public page (`Home/Index` for example), trying to "load/build" the app for the first time; it will indeed require a bit of time, due to build and such, but that's fine).

Now: when I try to load that empty `TestController`, it still takes lots of time:

[image]

How can this be possible? Does it compile each single controller separately? So every time I load a new controller (after publish the website or retart the pool) it will take that amount of time? I guess I'm wrong...

The second time I load it (and the following) is very faster:

[image]

How can I fix this? Where could it be the problem?

Note apart - this is my `Global.asax`, which shouldn't engrave:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }

    protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies["CookieFA"];
        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

            CustomPrincipal principal = new CustomPrincipal(authTicket.Name);
            CustomPrincipalSerializeModel userSerializeModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomPrincipalSerializeModel>(authTicket.UserData);
            principal.UserID = userSerializeModel.ID;
            principal.FirstName = userSerializeModel.FirstName;
            principal.LastName = userSerializeModel.LastName;
            principal.Roles = userSerializeModel.RoleName.ToArray<string>();

            HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Learn some basic ASP.NET debugging tips https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/tag/performance-issues-and-hangs/ and it would be easy to tell what's up.

Comment: There are a number of question on here about mvc application warmup.  Check out this one ttps://stackoverflow.com/a/47169875/187365

Comment: @Fran: even if I use `IProcessHostPreloadClient`, what do I write within it? Do I need to instance all controllers manually? :O

Comment: IProcessHostPreloadClient is used to pre-load and data you might want available at application start time.  Here's a [ink](https://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/asp-net-4-0-how-to-use-application-warm-up-class).  you've also go the [Application Initialization Module](https://serverfault.com/questions/373548/warming-up-an-iis-application-pool-automatically) for both IIS 7.5 and 8.0

Answer (score 2):

This happen because .NET build the view related with your action in the first request, it's the cause for the first request is slowly and the next ones faster. To improve it, you can build the views together with the application, exists some extensions that can do it for you as:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorGenerator.Mvc/
https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorGenerator.MsBuild/

You can read more in the RazorGenerator GitHub page about how to use these extension.